# Creating a chart of updating arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist, charts

I'm trying to create a chart with the x-axis as the time, and the y axis as values within an arraylist. These values update every 10 seconds.

I'm completely new with drawing charts in C#.

My code so far:

This method is used for creating the chart only once.

```
private void createChart()
    {
        chart.Size = new Size(600, 400);
        chart.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        chart.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        chart.Series.Add("Values");

        var chartArea = new ChartArea();
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm";
        chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
        chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

        var series = new Series();
        series.Name = "Series1";
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
        series.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart.Series.Add(series);

        tabpage3.Controls.Add(chart);
    }
```

This method is used for updating the charts:

The arraylist arraylistMonitor can contain 2 type of objects; chartObjectsInt and chartObjectsReal. This arraylist gets filled with more of these objects every 10 seconds with a timer_tick. If possible i would like to only obtain the last 10-20 objects in the the arraylist arraylistMonitor.

```
private void updateChart()
    {
        //Create datetime
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm").ToString();

        foreach (ChartObjectsInt chartRecords in arraylistMonitor)
        {
            if (chartRecords.getDataType() == "Int")
            {
                // bind the datapoints
                chart.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(time, chartRecords.getIntValue());
            }
        }

        foreach (ChartObjectsReal chartRecordsReal in arraylistMonitor)
        {
            if (chartRecordsReal.getDataType() == "Real")
            {
                // bind the datapoints
                chart.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(time, chartRecordsReal.getRealValue());
            }
        }

        // draw!
        chart.Invalidate();
    }
```

Im also getting an error with this code at the moment, see image:

[image: Error]

How do i get this work properly?

Thanks.

Comment: haven't used this before, but looks like `DataBindXY` isn't used for a single value but rather for a series of values, since it expects an `IEnumerable`

Comment: DataBindXY's second parameter expects IEnumerable[]...if you want to pass single value..may be you can wrap it in some IEnumerable collection....chart.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(time, new List<int>() { chartRecords.getIntValue()});

Comment: Abhay, ive tried this. Now im getting an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll". I dont even know if the code ive written before works. All im getting is a gray square.. I'm completely new with this and stuck at this point.

Comment: Replacing the (rather deprecated) ArrayList by a List<T> is a good start. I suggest to do it and edit the question to show new code. Aso do have a look intot the [various ways of DataBinding a Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).